# How do I change my Google password for authentication into Smule?

Tags: google-account

I need to change my password for authentication to sign into Smule. I have tried my Gmail addresses. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can access all your account settings at https://myaccount.google.com/ . More specifically, for your password, you need to go to https://myaccount.google.com/security/signinoptions/password